# C++ : pointer in vector and class inheritance

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance, vector

*Hi*, I'm C++ beginner, and I'm looking for a solution of the pointer now. I write source code first because my description skills of the English is too bad.(Thank you, google translator!) This is my code example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class UNIT
{
public :
    struct OBJ
    {
        float x,y,z;
    };
    vector<OBJ> obj;
    virtual void add(int x,int y,int z)=0;
    virtual void size()=0;
};
class KNIGHT : public UNIT
{
public :
    struct OBJ
    {
        float x,y,z;
    };
    vector<OBJ> obj;
    void add(int x,int y,int z)
    {
        OBJ sample;
        sample.x=x;
        sample.y=y;
        sample.z=z;
        obj.push_back(sample);
    }
    void size()
    {
        cout << obj.size() << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    KNIGHT knight;
    KNIGHT::OBJ sample_knight;
    UNIT* pt = &knight;

    pt->add(11,22,33);
    knight.obj.push_back(sample_knight);
    pt->size();
    cout << pt->obj.size() << endl;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

And result is

```
2
0
```

(If I access the **KNIGHT**'s variables likes **pt->obj[0].x** directly, it cause 'line 932 out of range')

From this experiment, I extracted the following results.

1. **UNIT* pt** didn't point to **KNIGHT**'s vector obj.
2. But the **UNIT* pt** can use **KNIGHT**'s **add()** and **size()**.
3. Probably it is associated with inheritance between **UNIT** and **KNIGHT**.

In addition, I'd tried **pt->obj.push_back()** (In this case, sample is **UNIT::OBJ**) and print **pt->obj.size()**, it showed me increased value. But **pt->size()** was the same as before. I expect it will cause problems of any kind at somewhere, and it is useless because it isn't connected with **KNIGHT**'s **add()** and **size()**.

So conclusion is this.

```
How can I get vector<OBJ> of KNIGHT(not UNIT) in directly, with UNIT* pointer or something?
```

※I'll use this in character pick function.

for example :

```
struct CHAR_LIST
{
    int type,num;
};
UNIT* Select_Unit(int type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
    case CHAR_KNIGHT :
        {
            return &knight;
        }
    case CHAR_ARCHER :
        {
            return &archer;
        }
    }
}
vector<CHAR_LIST> char_list;
UNIT* pt;
for (int num=0; num<char_list.size(); num++)
{
    pt = Select_Unit(char_list[num].type);
    pt->obj[char_list[num].num].x+=10;
    pt->obj[char_list[num].num].y=0;
}
```

Comment: Note that if you actually intended to hide the inherited names, you can access the base versions by doing something like `UNIT::obj` to access the base class version inside the derived class. (Replace `UNIT` with whatever the base name is, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different instances of the `vector<OBJ> obj`.  One in the base class and one in the derived class.  Because `KNIGHT` derives publicly from `UNIT` it has access to `UNIT`'s public `vector<OBJ> obj` and that's the one you want to use.  Instead you are redefining it in the base class.

Basically, `KNIGHT` should look like:

```
    class KNIGHT: public UNIT
    {
      public:
        void add(int x,int y,int z)
        {
            OBJ sample;
            sample.x=x;
            sample.y=y;
            sample.z=z;
            obj.push_back(sample);
        }
        void size()
        {
            cout << obj.size() << endl;
        }
    };
```

As an observation, it doesn't look like you need the functions `add` and `size` to be pure virtual (or even virtual) and you could just define them in the class `UNIT`.  If, however, you want some other class to have a different behaviour when calling `add` or `size` then you want to keep them virtual.

I somehow missed the last line where you actually asked the question.  The thing is that the `UNIT*` can only access what's in the `UNIT` class.  It has no idea that it's actually pointing to a `KNIGHT` object.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going to have to use the method that get down individual characteristics to reluctantly if there is no way exists..

Answer (score 2):

The `OBJ` and `obj` in `KNIGHT` hide those in `UNIT`. Comment them out and try again:

```
class KNIGHT : public UNIT
{
public :
    // struct OBJ
    // {
    //     float x,y,z;
    // };
    // vector<OBJ> obj;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Certainly, out of range does not occur. But I want various types of units what have own values..(for the polymorphism) Is there no way for indivisual's OBJ struct?